# How do i get XPSdrv to print a pdf

Tags: c++, windows, printing, driver

I have the XPSdrv from microsoft sample code up and running (https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/print/XPSDrvSmpl).

How do I get this to print a pdf instead of an xps?

I have read a few comments stating that you change this in the code relatively easy, but I am new to driver development, and do not know where to start

Comment: I thought this was going to be an easy answer. I had a recollection that there was a standard PDF render filter for V4 XPSDrv printer drivers, but it seems there's not. I wonder if it was removed? Anyway, if it helps, there's standard render filters for converting your XPS in the driver, to either PCL or PostScript. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/print/standard-xps-filters

Comment: Aside from that, unless anyone else can think of a different solution, you'll need to write your own render filter to convert either the XPS bytes or parts that you're given, into a PDF stream. There's plenty of components around (I believe). The Mako SDK is one of them. (Disclaimer, I'm a Developer Advocate for the Mako SDK.)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow by the way! :) I hope you find it useful!

Comment: @Andy, Thank you very much for your comments. I have been going through the microsoft documentation already, but will re-read the link you gave me. It is not the most strait forward documentation I have read so far.

Writing my own render filter might be the way I need to go. Thank you for the information, It will give me something to look more into.

Comment: No worries, printer driver development can be difficult at the best of times. V4 drivers make it a little easier, but still keep a lot of complicated baggage from the V3 days. Shout if we can be of help.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, as far as I know, there's no simple way to change the mentioned sample to output PDF.

What you'll need to do is add a new render filter at the end the XPS filter pipeline. This filter will take the XPS stream, or parts, and convert it into PDF to be streamed out.

See IHV rendering filter here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/print/v4-driver-rendering-architecture

Note, the above link is for V4 drivers, but the same filter can be used for a V3 filter pipeline.

If you're find with support for Windows 10 and onwards, you may want to consider a V4 printer driver instead of the V3 sample you found.

The benefits are that you can use WPF to create your driver's UI, rather than MFC with a V3 driver. You also have less C++ to write for conversions between private devmodes and print tickets. These conversions are required to get your settings into the filter pipeline.

There was at one stage, a deprecation plan for V3 too, although this has since been lifted.

Comment: Hi Andy, Thank you for this information.
A V4 driver could actually be quite beneficial in the long run from what I have read. I can try switching to create one of those instead.

Would you happen to know any resources that would be available to get started with this?

I would mark this answer as useful, but unfortunately I do not have enough reputation to do so.

Comment: I think there should be a project template V4 printer driver project shipped with Visual Studio. What workload it comes under, I'm less sure! :) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/print/build-a-v4-print-driver-in-visual-studio. Oddly, when I tried this project a number of years back when V4 was fairly new, I struggled to get it working (there may be a Stack Overflow post on it), but if you haven't tried it recently, you might want to. I'm sure they might have fixed up the template.

Comment: Hi Andy, Thank you for went through the process of getting it compiled and installed, but unfortunately it seems that this is a printer FOR xps files, and not to create xps files. I was not able to get it installed in a way that let me solve my issues.

Comment: Hey, so it uses the same XPS filter pipeline, so you're right that it uses XPS as a spool format (input), and I think IIRC, it outputs XPS too by default. If you use the driver and do a print-to-file from notepad, you should see the file (once renamed to .XPS) is an XPS. What you do next depends on your workflow. If you want users to choose a save location, you can use the FileSave section and PortPrompt port monitor with your printer driver. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/print/v4-driver-manifest#filesave-section. If you want to programmatically select a location...

Comment: ... you'll need to update your render filter to impersonate the user using the user token XPS_FP_USER_TOKEN in the filter pipeline property bag, which will allow you to redirect the XPS stream coming into your render filter to an XPS file on disk. This would be where you do your conversion to PDF, if required.